# undefined method `config' for Trello:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, trello

I am using the ruby-trello gem (https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello), and have been for some time with no issue.  Today, the console is giving me this error:

```
undefined method `config' for Trello:Module
```

I'm fairly certain this has nothing to do with this gem but rather, I suspect it has something to do with either rvm or some other issue.

I'm seeing the same issue with Ruby-1.9.3 and Ruby-2.0.0.  As far as I can tell, nothing has changed, no code commits, no Rails versions, but obviously something must have changed because this appeared all of the sudden.

UPDATE

backtrace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `config' for Trello:Module
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-      3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Comment: Required fill back trace to investigate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be rvm.  Imploding and then reinstalling rvm and rubies fixed this.